HTTP Cookie policy SameSite on localhost works on Safari but not Firefox or Chrome [SOLVED]
I am running a localhost development version of my website.
I am refactoring into subdomains and have a problem reading the session cookies (PHP and my own) across the subdomain boundaries.
I now have it working correctly on Safari but Firefox and Chrome still refuse to cooperate.
I suspect that this is problem related to localhost and https over localhost issues but don't want to modify my remote server to test without knowing this is going to work.
Localhost is served over HTTPS with selfsigned certs and my only theory is that this is causing Firefox and Chrome to consider (for the sake of cookie management) that this is an unsecure connection (therefor invalidating SameSite) even though the overall connection is indeed secure (HTTPS).   I have this theory because Safari has access to keychain user trust overrides which the other browsers may be ignoring.
Specifics:
sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, and example.com all need access to the same cookies.
likewise for..
sub1.localhost, sub2.localhost, and localhost
session is created at localhost... attempting to read at sub1.localhost
Chrome says: "This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current url".
Firefox (dev) says: "Cookie “PHPSESSID” has been rejected for invalid domain."
Safari however operates as expected with PHPSESSID cookie created for localhost being available at sub1.localhost.
Cookie: (set by localhost) has these attributes set as follows:
Domain:"localhost"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:true
Path:"/"
SameSite:"None"
Secure:true
I also tried sending "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost" and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://*.localhost" headers without any change in behavior.
Environment:
Apache/2.4.62 OpenSSL/3.3.2 PHP/8.2.23 MacOS/10.13.6
Chrome 116, Firefox 82-DEV, Safari 13.1.2, Firefox 115-ESR
UPDATE:
Solution finally found at this other SO Question:
Configure a cookie to work with CORS, but only on subdomains
The issue is with the fact that localhost is not a properly formed domain name. Changed local site from localhost to example.local solved the problem.
